# Why am I getting the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page instead of my own index.html page?

Tags: apache2

I have an Ubuntu 14.10 computer that is used for **local** website testing, it is not serving to the internet. On it, I have seven websites set up. However, when I access two of the seven, I get the `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` instead of my own index page.

As far as I can tell, I set up all seven using the exact same process, so I don't know what these two are missing. Also, in my Apache logs directory, I have two log files, `error` and `access` for each of the two misbehaving sites, but all of them are empty. When I restart the `apache2` service, there are no errors. I have retraced my steps multiple times and I can not see any difference between the working sites and the non working sites.

What options do I have for diagnosing this problem? Can I force more verbose error logs somehow? Is there another log somewhere that I can reference?

Here is an example of a `.conf` file for one of the malfunctioning sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.local_example.com
   ServerAlias local_example.com
   ServerAdmin address@example.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/Websites/example.com
   <Directory /var/www/Websites/example.com/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       # pcw AllowOverride None
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
       # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
       # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
       # Commented out for Ubuntu
       #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog /home/example/Apache_Logs/local_example.com_error.log

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
   # alert, emerg.
   LogLevel warn

   CustomLog /home/example/Apache_Logs/local_example.com_access.log combined
   ServerSignature On

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How did you create the virtual hosts? Did you create them by adding files to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`? If so, did you enable them with `sudo a2ensite <your_site_name>`? Does the default apache error log file have anything in it? And do you have a ServerAlias or ServerName configured in your virtual host files? If you disable the default site `sudo a2dissite 000-default` (you can re-enable it with `sudo a2ensite 000-default`), does it work? Also, it could be that you just forgot to restart apache?

Comment: @Dan, thank you for responding. I created the sites by adding them to `sites-available`. The default error log has nothing in it. I have defined `ServerAlias` in the hosts file. I disabled the `000-default` site but that did not change anything. I restarted and reloaded apache many times.

Comment: When you disabled the default site and restarted apache, it was still showing the default index.html page, or was it showing one from a different virtual host? Can you post the content of one of the misbehaving vhost files? This might make things much easier for us to help.

Comment: @Dan, Thank you for respondng. When I made the change you suggested, as I mentioned, nothing changed, meaning that it showed the exact same default index page. I've added a `.conf` file to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was permissions.

When you're storing the web site in a directory outside of `/var/www` and connected by symlink, then the source directory, *and its parent directory* have to have permissions of `755`.

For some unknown reason, the two misbehaving sites had different permissions, and running `chmod -R 755` on the web site directory, and its *parent* directory, solved the problem.

Comment: You should not run `chmod -R 755` on a directory because all the files in there are going to be marked as "executable"...

Comment: @AlexisWilke, what is a better command for setting the right permissions?

Comment: There isn't an easy one to change the permissions of all the directories and not the standard... You can use `find` though. Something like this: `find top-dir-name -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`.

Answer (score 12):

For me, one of the suggestions from @Dan solved it.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
service apache2 reload
```

Apparently the default site configuration was overriding my vhost configuration.

Comment: In other server it behaved differently and index.php was read instead of index.html. Very sneaky situation

Answer (score 10):

Try the following

**Enable verbose logs**

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Locate the LogLevel variable, and update it from the default warn to info or debug. debug will produce the greatest amount of output.

```
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
# 
LogLevel debug
```

**Restart Apache**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Apache includes a nice little syntax checking tool

```
apache2ctl -t
```

Checking Virtual Host Definitions

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I set the log level to debug, and I am still getting absolutely no entries in the error log files. The access logs now show every time I opened the sites, but nothing else.

Comment: Thank you. You made my day.

Answer (score 4):

after installation index.html has higher priority that's why you still seeing default Ubuntu page
check this folder var/www/html/
rename or remove this page
simple as that

Answer (score 3):

I battled with the same issue.

I even deleted `/var/www/html`, did `sudo a2dissite 000-default` and deleted `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and even then, the issue persisted.

In the end I figured out that the `index.html` was persisted due to some hardcoding in the c++ code.

The built in default `DirectoryIndex` is in `/mods-available/dir.conf` and goes like this:

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm`

My project had no `index.html` just an `index.php`

The solution was to add a `DirectoryIndex` to my vhost .conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mysite">
   RewriteEngine On
   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   Require all granted
        
   #extra config to disable default index.html
   DirectoryIndex disabled
   DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

This solved the issue completely for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info that it's probably hardcoded in C/C++ . For me I just added index.html in  /var/www/html, it worked fine and showed some kind of new default behaviour (in the past defautl "index.html" was real not virtual)